# Why this knockout custom binding is working only for first element of foreach?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to generate a tabbed navigation list. I am using `foreach` binding of knockout, but it is rendering the template only for the first item in the list.

If I remove the custom binding `i18nTranslateText` and simply use `text` binding instead of it, then `foreach` renders both the items in the `tabs` array.

`UPDATE:` If I comment out the line `viewModel.LanguageSelected.subscribe(...);` then also, this works properly for both items in the list.

Where I am doing mistake?

```
$(function () {

ko.bindingHandlers.i18nTranslateText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var param1 = valueAccessor(); // not used, but could be used.
        $(element).html(jQuery.i18n.prop(param1));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var param1 = valueAccessor(); // not used, but could be used.
        $(element).html(jQuery.i18n.prop(param1));

        viewModel.LanguageSelected.subscribe(function (key) {

            if (key == 'English') {

                viewModel.loadBundles('en');
            }
            else {
                viewModel.loadBundles('es');
            }

            $(element).html(jQuery.i18n.prop(param1));

        }.bind(this));
    }
};

var View = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(View.Load());
});

function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.tabs = ['abc', 'xyz'];
    self.Load = function () {
    return self;
    }
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
    <li>
    <a href="#" data-bind="i18nTranslateText: $data"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how is `tabs` populated

Comment: there isnt even a property called "tabs"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it while I was simplifying my code to post here.  I have added it now.

Comment: Can you get a jsFiddle running, showing your problem?

Comment: If I simply use 'text' binding instead of 'i18nTranslateText' then this works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there is no property `LanguageSelected` defined on the view model. This is what's happening,

1. ko picks up the array starts the foreach rendering. now index i = 0, and starts.
2. hits the `i18nTranslateText` part for the item at index i in the array
3. calls `init` on the custom binding handler. Works, updates the element html
4. now calls `update` on the custom binding handler.
5. execution reaches `viewModel.LanguageSelected.subscribe` and this raises a script error `Uncaught TypeError - undefined`. So execution stops and you end up with one item displayed

In your second scenario, if you comment out the `viewModel.LanguageSelected.subscribe`, then all is fine. This is the answer to your specific question, but I guess the view model pasted in the question is still incomplete. Hope this helps!

Comment: You are right, but I identified it yesterday, few hours after posting this question. I was doing knockout stuff after 1 year, so couldn't get it working fast. I have voted you +1. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it helped jog your memory, thanks for the accept!